# Alternatives to Query String in HttpGet for sending data?

Tags: c#, xml, rest, query-string, asp.net-web-api

I am developing a REST API and currently client sends data in QueryString. For one method client need to send relatively large data (XML content). Due to query string size limitation I am looking for alternatives.

What are ways to send data in HttpGet request other than query string?

Comment: Just curious, why don't you use POST to send data?

Comment: Because based on XML I return some data. POST isn't made for this I believe

Comment: Due to the HTTP protocol, always a response is sent.

Comment: Well the only two options are going to be Querystring or in the body of a POST/PUT. You are letting the concept of "REST" get in the way of you accomplishing your task.

Comment: It does not matter much, POST also can return data to consumer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though you are correct about using the `@GET` you are facing a [practical limitation(Section 5.2)](http://www.w3.org/2001/tag/doc/whenToUseGet.html) of implementations. You would have to go with `@POST` for your method if your queryString is considerabily big.

Answer (score 0):

Passing data using query strings in the URL is for the `GET` method. You could use `PUT` or `POST`. This way you can paste your data in the request object (simply put the query string in the request instead of the URL).

Comment: But I believe POST is for posting data. This method is purely for retuning user some data based on XML he sends.

Comment: From the HTTP Spec: 

"If a resource has been created on the origin server, the response SHOULD be 201 (Created) and contain an entity which describes the status of the request and refers to the new resource, and a Location header (see section 14.30)."

I see no reason not to use it.